# Connecting a 16 pin camera

Tags: pi-3, camera

I've just deconstructed an old cheap drone I had laying around with a camera on board, and its a 16 pin 1080p camera. Can I, and if so, how, connect the 16 pin camera to the 40 pin camera input on the RPI3?

Answer (score 0):

Check the board on the camera for a manufacturer and model, there's slim chance you'll be able to get some technical info and, if luck is still with you, somebody somewhere will have made a USB adapter. If you can go via USB you may be able to use generic drivers?

The more boring answer is that the raspberry pi camera is ~£20, in the unlikely event you find an adapter board for you current camera odds on it not much different in price and still isn't guaranteed to work.

http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/video-modules/9132664/

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! Sadly nothing showed up for the camera, but looking closer on the pi camera the ribbon cable looks similar in size (guesstimation from pictures), which is then converted into a wider ribbon cable... Could this be a generic board I could find?

Comment: Even if the ribbon cable is the same that won't matter. The Pi's camera firmware is very specific to the two sensor models (OV5647 and IMX219) available (this is perfectly normal for cameras of this ilk). If the drone's sensor is different it simply won't work even if the interface is the same (unless by some miracle all its hardware registers and operating characteristics precisely match those of the supported sensors!)

Comment: @DaveJones cool, I learned something new! So with that knowledge - am I in a hopeless situation? I still have the original board it was connected to - and the board has an SD card slot where the pictures were saved to. My hope is that I can somehow take this board and instead of having it save to the SD card, show the feed live - or at least save to my RPi.

Comment: The live feed is very likely impossible. There's a serious amount of (sensor specific) work that goes into making that sort of thing happen. The [camera hardware chapter](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html) in the picamera docs gives some idea of what goes on under the hood. Your best hope is, as Craig suggests, to try and find some form of USB adapter that implements all that but the likelihood is a straight pi camera module is likely cheaper (and more flexible).